# how to search using datetime picker in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is my code behind

```
If DateTimePicker.DateTime <> "" Then
    If opt = "" Then
        opt = " where "
    Else
        opt = " and "
    End If
    Dim POcompletedate As String = DateTimePicker.DateTime
    Dim POcompletedate2 As String = DateTimePicker.DateTime
    POcompletedate2 = POcompletedate.Substring(6, 4) +  POcompletedate.Substring(3, 2) + POcompletedate.Substring(0, 2)
    sqlPOComplete.SelectCommand = sqlPOComplete.SelectCommand + opt
    sqlPOComplete.SelectCommand = sqlPOComplete.SelectCommand + "GRIRCompleteDate = CAST('" 
    sqlPOComplete.SelectCommand = sqlPOComplete.SelectCommand + POcompletedate2
    sqlPOComplete.SelectCommand = sqlPOComplete.SelectCommand + "' AS datetime) "
End If
```

Comment: It looks like you're referencing the control type `DateTimePicker` and not the control name. Also, can you clearly explain what issue you're having?

Comment: im trying to search an item based on date pick by the user.

Comment: Use the Name of your control, and not the control type. Then inspect the .Value property to test for a date value. Also, research using command parameters so that you don't have to cast it in the query.